# Will the Thread Pool create more than {num of cores} Threads in a "pure async" program?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, threadpool

Consider a theoretical "pure async" .NET  program (a web server, for that matter)- no thread ever gets blocked,  all I/O's are completely asynchronous. Now, suppose there is a heavy load on that server, and requests (**Tasks**) are queued faster than they are enqueued (due to I/O latency). Obviously, in that case more than num_of_cores Threads won't improve the throughput -  the server is simply at it's limit. But, will the ThreadPool recognize that fact or will it try to create more and more thread to decrease the pressure on the Tasks buffer?

*num_of_cores refers to the number of logical cores the OS sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, will the ThreadPool recognize that fact or will it try to create
>   more and more thread to decrease the pressure on the Tasks buffer?

The CLR thread-pool isn't aware of the actual number of IO Request Packets (IRQ) that can be handled by the underlying OS. It has an artifical limit which is set in the VM implementation of the threadpool:

```
SVAL_IMPL_INIT(LONG,ThreadpoolMgr,MaxLimitTotalCPThreads,1000);
```

You can yourself alter that value by calling `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. When you do that, the VM does this:

```
MaxLimitTotalCPThreads = 
        min(MaxIOCompletionThreads, (DWORD)ThreadCounter::MaxPossibleCount);
```

Where `ThreadCounter::MaxPossibleCount` is equal to `0x7FFF` (524287) completion port threads.

The thread-pool tries it's best to abstract those operations from you, and that is something you shouldn't really worried about. Let the thread-pool balance the work for you, allocating and destroying threads as needed. Worst case scenario, you'll start noticing latency with respect to your IO operations, but I'm pretty sure it will take some effort on your part to actually hit that ceiling.

Generally, if you're interested in the native implementation, you can [browse it on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp)

Comment: I was asking only out of curiosity, I have no intention of messing around with those configurations.

Comment: @shay__ It's alright to touch those configurations if you find cases where you can benefit from them. My answer includes a "general" guideline, as people might see this answer in the future who aren't only asking this for knowledge :).